# Sublime text2, Replace all messes up the upper-case lower-case

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

The replace all option messes up the lower-case formation in Sublime Text 2. For example:

When I want to replace all the classes named "example1" to "hidethis"
I get "hideThis".

This is getting annoying, especially when I am going to do this procedure to URLs.

Is there any way to disable that option?

Comment: You must be doing something else, because that's not how search and replace works.

Comment: Why would it affect URLs?  URLs are not case-sensitive...

Comment: That's why I got so confused. I thought maybe someone else who encountered the problem may see this.

Comment: I have just encountered the same with Sublime Text 3. ☹